# Need to achieve 120 hits per second in Jmeter during loadtest

Tags: api, jmeter, load-testing

I have 5 thread groups each one have 3 api requests and each thread should execute one after one, in 1 hour load test should achieve 120 hits per second.
Pacing: 5 sec
Thinktime: 8 sec
Each thread single iteration time: 20 sec
So for this how much users I need to give to achieve required 120 hits per second and how can I do load test for 5 thread groups because each one should execute one after one.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of simple arithmetic calculations and I believe question should go to https://math.stackexchange.com/ (or alternatively you can catch a student of the nearest school ask ask him)

> `Each thread single iteration time: 20 sec`

means that each user executes 3 requests per 20 seconds, to wit 1 request per 6.6 seconds.

So you need 6.6 users to get 1 request per second or 792 users to reach 120 requests per second.

Also "pacing" concept is for the the "dumb" tools which don't support setting the desired throughput and JMeter provides:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
2. [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
3. [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

any of them provides possibility to define the number of requests per second, especially the latter one which can be connected with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)